# Not able to click on a link in a frame

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, frame, webdriverwait

I am not able to click a link in a frame in run mode. First I switched to Frame and then click on a link. After clicking the link, I want to click on another link on the same frame. But not able to click on the second link. In Debug mode, I am able to click both the link.

Used URL: http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html

There are three frames on the page and I switch to frame named "classFrame". On the Frame, I click on the link named "Deprecated". I got all the content of "Deprecated" link. Now I want to click on "Overview" link where I was before. But I am not able to click on link named "Overview". Please help me to click on the second link "Overview".
 I am using following code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait webWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 1000);
    driverChrome.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html");

    driverChrome.switchTo().frame("classFrame");

    driverChrome.findElement(By.linkText("Deprecated")).click();
    WebElement linkOverview = driverChrome.findElement(By.linkText("Overview"));
    webWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(linkOverview));
    driverChrome.findElement(By.linkText("Overview")).click();
```

For page HTML code, Please refer the link as I am not able to paste it here. Thank you very much

Comment: you probably want to use a wait on findElement, too.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Deprecated** within the url http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html and again `click()` on the element with text as **Overview**, as the the desired element is within a `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - `cssSelector`:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
    driverChrome.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html");
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[name='classFrame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.topNav a[href^='deprecated-list']"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.topNav a[href^='overview-summary']"))).click();
    ```
  - `xpath`:

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
    driverChrome.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/deprecated.html");
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='classFrame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='topNav']//a[starts-with(@href, 'deprecated-list')]"))).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='topNav']//a[starts-with(@href, 'overview-summary')]"))).click();
    ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks For the reply. I am able to click on "Depricated" link first but not able to click link "Overview" after "Depricated". Please let me know other way

Comment: @Achiver Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB. I have used elementToBeClickable for second link "Overview" and it worked. Thank you very much